# three.js textured material does not take lighting

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I wonder if a textured geometry can take lighting in three.js. In my scene, all materials get great lighting with spotLight and directionalLight except for materials with texture assignment like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry(1, 0)
var orange =  new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'img/orange.jpg' );
orange.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
orange.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
orange.repeat.set( 4, 2);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    map:orange, side:THREE.DoubleSide 
    });

var oct0 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    oct0.castShadow = true; //default is false
    oct0.receiveShadow = false; //default
    scene.add( oct0 );
    oct0.position.x = 0;
    oct0.position.y = 5;
    oct0.position.z = 0;
```

I am using Chrome. Safari and three.js r89. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `MeshBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights. Try `MeshPhongMaterial`, for example.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley that indeed worked!

Answer (score 1):

`MeshBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights.

There are other built-in materials that do. For example, `MeshLambertMaterial`, `MeshPhongMaterial`, `MeshStandardMaterial`.

three.js r.89